# Protect Against Redis Key Eviction Policy

Tags: php, caching, redis, key

So I'm adding Redis to a project and I'm in the process of wrapping database calls with cache calls.

If I have a query like this in a model (and the model simply returns the data to the controller):

```
"SELECT * FROM countries";
```

My plan is to cache each country in a data structure like this:

```
$cache->hmset("country:1", ['id' => 1, name => 'Ireland']);// 250+ more countries
```

And to also maintain a SET data structure of country ids, like this:

```
$cache->sadd("countries", 1);
```

**QUESTION**

In the case of retrieving all countries, do I need to write logic to populate both redis data structures in the event that either of them are not already in the cache?
For example, should my countries model look like this:

```
    // Check cache for set of valid countries IDs
    if (!$cache->exists("countries")) {
        $ids = "SELECT id FROM countries";// Pretend $ids is array for simplicity

        // Add countries IDs into cache
        $cache->sadd("countries", $ids);
    }

    /* At this point we know the set of country IDs exists */

    $country_ids = $cache->smembers("countries");

    $response = [];

    /* Retrieve each country */
    foreach ($country_ids as $id) {
        /* If "countries:{$id}" is not in cache */
        if (!$cache->exists("countries:{$id}")) {// Retrieve country from database
            $entity = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE countries.id = {$id}";// Pretend $entity is array of fields for simplicity

            // Set country entity into cache
            $cache->hset("countries:{$id}", $entity);
        } else {
            $entity = $cache->hgetall("countries:{$id}");
        }

        $response[] = $entity;
    }

    return $response;
```

UPDATE

The countries table is just sample data but it represents any table that is being read from and written to regularly. The cache must always represent whats stored in the database, so when we insert a new entity or update an existing one we also update the cache. 
There are also multiple other keys and user data stored in the cache and there may be situations where the cache evicts certain keys, and some of the requests to the cache may result in nothing being found.

My question is: How do you guarantee that the data thats expected to be found in the cache is either:
 A) Found in the cache, or 
 B) Not found in the cache, and so we put it in the cache

AND

Does every request to get something from the cache require us to run a database query to retrieve the data from our database and then put it in the cache, as outlined in the example above?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The answer depends on the purpose of your `countries` SET. Please provide more information

Comment: @thepirat000 thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think it otherwise, use a [cache-aside pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx) and have the logic to retrieve/insert from cache on the **Get** operation.

See this psedo-code for an example (sorry I'm not familiar with php):

```
function GetCountry($id)
{
    if ($cache->hexists("countries:{$id}")) {
        $entity = $cache->hgetall("countries:{$id}");
    }
    else
    {
        $entity = $database.GetCountry($id);
        $cache->hmset("country:{$id}", ['id' => $entity->id, ... ]);
    }
    return $entity;
}

function AddCountry($country)
{
    $database.AddCountry($country);
}

function UpdateCountry($id, $data)
{
    $database.UpdateCountry($id, $data);
    $cache->del("country:{$id}");
}

function DeleteCountry($id)
{
    $database.DeleteCountry($id);
    $cache->del("country:{$id}");
}
```

So you never **update** the cache, you just add to the cache when the object is retrieved for the first time, and invalidate the key after updating/deleting the entities.